# How to make `CommandInteraction.reply()` return a `Message` using the discord API

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have the following (typescript) code snippet that generates an embed in response to an interaction, and sends it:

```js
const embed = await this.generateEmbed(...);
await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]});
const sentMessage: Message = <Message<boolean>> await interaction.fetchReply();
await sentMessage.react('⬅');
```

However, this fails at runtime because `TypeError: sentMessage.react is not a function`.

This is somewhat explained [in the discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Webhook?scrollTo=fetchMessage):

> Returns the raw message data if the webhook was instantiated as a WebhookClient or if the channel is uncached, otherwise a Message will be returned

However, this happens even if I cache everything:

```js
const bot = new Client({
    makeCache: Options.cacheEverything(),
    ...
});
```

Also note that I'm not using a `WebhookClient` here.

Why is `CommandInteraction.reply()` returning a raw message here, and how can I make it return a full `Message` object, so that I can use the `.react()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done quite a bit of testing and I've come to the conclusion that this is happening because you're not requesting the [`GUILDS`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS) intent. I'm assuming that without the [`GUILDS`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS) intent, the [`GuildChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel) cannot be cached, nor the [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message), so it returns the raw data from the API.

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS],
    ...
})
```

Comment: Excellent deduction thank you! For future users, this can be fixed using `const bot = new Client({ intents: [ Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, ... ]});` when you create the client.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.